# React useEffect with async/await issue

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I am trying to add some properties to an array of objects inside useEffect but it renders DOM while those fields are still not present. Is there any reliable way how to wait till those properties are added:

useEffect hook look like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    onSnapshot(query(collection(db, "conversations"), where('canRead', 'array-contains', user.user.uid), orderBy("lastMsgDate", 'desc')),
      async (snapshot) => {
        let conversations = snapshot.docs.map(doc => toConversation(doc, user.user.uid));
        await conversations.map(async (convo, index) => {
          const profile = await getDoc(doc(db, "users", convo.canRead[0]))
          conversations[index].picture = profile.data().picture
          conversations[index].name = profile.data().name
        })
        setConversations(conversations)
      })
  }, []);
```

This is how I am rendering list of convos:

```
<IonCard>
  {conversations.length > 0 ?
    conversations.map((conversation) =>
      <IonItem key={conversation.id}>
        <IonAvatar slot='start'>
          <img src={conversation.picture ? conversation.picture : '/assets/default-profile.svg'} alt={conversation.name} />
        </IonAvatar>
        <IonLabel>{conversation.name}</IonLabel>
      </IonItem>
    )
    :
    <IonCardContent>
      no convos
    </IonCardContent>
  }
</IonCard>
```

the name and picture does not render even i can see it when log array into console

```
0:{ 
  canRead: ['iwPmOBesFQV1opgs3HT9rYPF7Sj1'],
  id: "W6cefXGoBAZijPof8jVl",
  lastMsg: "test",
  lastMsgDate: nt {seconds: 1668418292, nanoseconds: 281000000},
  lastMsgSender: "Hyw4Argt8rR25mFaFo1Sl4iAWoM2",
  name: "Warren"
  picture: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/..."
  users: {
    Hyw4Argt8rR25mFaFo1Sl4iAWoM2: true,
    iwPmOBesFQV1opgs3HT9rYPF7Sj1: true
  }
}
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Add the variables you want the useEffect to update to the dependency array. This will cause the callback in the useEffect to rerun.

Comment: @Igor Mizak How you are rendering ?, are you referring to conversations ?.Please share the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loading message or a gif.

```
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

 useEffect(() => {
   onSnapshot(query(collection(db, "conversations"), where('canRead', 'array-contains', user.user.uid), orderBy("lastMsgDate", 'desc')),
      async (snapshot) => {
        ....
        setConversations(conversations);
        setLoading(false);
      })
 }, []);

 if(loading) return <p>Loading...</p>

 return <> your content </>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u can add a loading state? something like

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [conversations,setConversations] = useState(null);
  const onSnapshot = async () => {
    setLoading(true)
    onSnapshot(
      query(
        collection(db, "conversations"),
        where("canRead", "array-contains", user.user.uid),
        orderBy("lastMsgDate", "desc")
      ),
      async (snapshot) => {
        let conversations = snapshot.docs.map((doc) =>
          toConversation(doc, user.user.uid)
        );
        await conversations.map(async (convo, index) => {
          const profile = await getDoc(doc(db, "users", convo.canRead[0]));
          conversations[index].picture = profile.data().picture;
          conversations[index].name = profile.data().name;
        });
        setConversations(conversations);
      }
    );

    setLoading(false);
  };
 
  useEffect(() => {
    onSnapshot()
  },[])

  return loading ? <span>loading...</span> : <div>{conversations.map((con,i) => <span key={i}>con</span>)}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

for some reason it works with `setTimeout` function which is not the best solution

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading({ loading: true, loadingMsg: 'Loading conversations' })
    onSnapshot(query(collection(db, "conversations"), where('canRead', 'array-contains', user.user.uid), orderBy("lastMsgDate", 'desc')),
      async (snapshot) => {
        let convos = snapshot.docs.map(doc => toConversation(doc, user.user.uid));
        await convos.map(async (convo, index) => {
          const profile = await getDoc(doc(db, "users", convo.canRead[0]))
          convos[index].picture = profile.data().picture
          convos[index].name = profile.data().name
        })
        setTimeout(() => {
          setConversations(convos)
          setLoading({ loading: false, loadingMsg: undefined })
        }, 1000);
      })
  }, [user.user.uid]);
```